# How to access data in out side post method in axios

Tags: axios

I have tried to get data and assign into 'data ', so please may I know how can I access this drugName value in outside?

AddItems(id) {

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/Drug/' + id).then(
        function(response) {
            console.log('response.JSON:', {
                message: 'Request received',
                data: response.data["0"].drugName,
            })
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: The call will be `Async`. So even assigning to some variable won't work in this case. With which library are you using `axios`?

Comment: are you using Vue JS by any chance? if not your only way is to create a global variable and store it there so you can use it in other parts of your page or functions

Comment: @IamCavic how can I store it in global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
function axiosTest() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/Drug/' + id).then((response) => {
        return response.data["0"].drugName,
    });
}

axiosTest().then(data => {
  response.json({ message: 'Request received!', data })
})
```

Comment: thank you,I need use this value in post method, so how should I do?

Comment: Make another request (POST) from the axiosTest().then(data => {
  response.json({ message: 'Request received!', data })
})